# IPSec site to site VPN

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec

I am trying to connect our server to cisco site-to-site IPSec VPN with one of our partners servers, they asked us to implement the settings they gave us into our router, but actually we don't have access to the router, we are just connected directly with our ISP. alternatively, we were informed that we can use software VPN instead, and yes we found a working one, tested and verified, but we have to pay for it to keep running.

Now my question is, having that we are running windows server 2012 R2, how can we establish this VPN connection directly from windows without the need to use third parties tools?

The only parameter that we have to connect are:

Gateway IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Authentication Pre-shared Key: ######

Encryption: 3DES

Hash authentication: MD5

DH: Group1

No username or password is needed with this type of VPN.

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards,
Abed

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/695344/ipsec-vpn-set-up-windows) is a very similar question. You'll just need to change the encryption types in the steps of the answer there to the ones you need.